# nice numbers in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm a novice at SQL so please pardon my white spaces. I'm trying to write a query in sqlite to give me two values namely:

1. The sum of all the values in a column (budget) with a distinct value
   from another column (spent) and converting the values to thousands,
   millions, billions using k, M and B concatenated as the suffix
2. Subtracting a due date (date) from the current date ('now') and
   getting values in days.

This is the query I used but the results seem a little off and not accurate:

```
SELECT ( CASE 1 
WHEN SUM(Budget >= 1000 AND Budget < 10000) THEN  '$' || 
substr(Budget,1,1) || '.' || substr(Budget,2,1)  || 'K'
WHEN SUM(Budget  >= 10000 AND Budget < 100000) THEN '$' || 
substr(Budget,1,2) || '.' || substr(Budget,3,1)  || 'K'
WHEN SUM(Budget >= 100000 AND Budget < 1000000) THEN '$' || 
substr(Budget,1,3) || '.' || substr(Budget,4,1)  || 'K'
WHEN SUM(Budget >= 1000000 AND Budget < 10000000) THEN  '$' || 
substr(Budget,1,1) || '.' || substr(Budget,2,1)  || 'M'
WHEN SUM(Budget >= 10000000 AND Budget < 100000000) THEN '$' || 
substr(Budget,1,2) || '.' || substr(Budget,3,1)  || 'M'
WHEN SUM(Budget >= 100000000 AND Budget < 1000000000) THEN '$' || 
substr(Budget,1,3) || '.' || substr(Budget,4,1)  || 'M'
WHEN SUM(Budget >= 1000000000 AND Budget < 10000000000) THEN  '$' || 
substr(Budget,1,1) || '.' || substr(Budget,2,1)  || 'B'
WHEN SUM(Budget >= 10000000000 AND Budget < 100000000000) THEN '$' || 
substr(Budget,1,2) || '.' || substr(Budget,3,1)  || 'B'
WHEN SUM(Budget >= 100000000000 AND Budget < 1000000000000) THEN '$' || 
substr(Budget,1,3) || '.' || substr(Budget,4,1)  || 'B'
ELSE ''
END) AS budget,
(SELECT cast(
     (
              strftime('%d',eventDate)-strftime('%d','now')
     ) AS real
  )) AS days_left, (SELECT (count(spent)) AS total_spent FROM 
`user_selected_items` WHERE `userID` = 'userID' 
AND `Status` IN('0')) AS total_items_left FROM `user_selected_items`
```

Comment: Provide an example data set and the output you desire from that data set.

Comment: I've removed the MySQL tag from your question since you make it clear in the title and first paragraph that this is for SQLite, not MySQL.  Those are two distinct products.

Comment: @user1735921 for example in a "user table" where the "Budget" column is 54000000, instead of outputing $54000000 i would want it to output $54m.

Comment: Thanks in advance